# How to set TextField on the top using Javafx?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

HiEveryone,

I'm a beginner in `Javafx` and trying to set `TextField` on the top and I'm using `GridPane`. So i tried this code but that's giving me errors:

Source code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;

public class Main extends Application {
        @Override
        public void start (Stage primaryStage){
        primaryStage.setTitle("Modern web browser made by Rajendra Arora using JavaFX.");
        WebView wv = new WebView();
        WebEngine we = wv.getEngine();
        we.load("http://www.google.com/");

        TextField tf = new TextField("http://www.google.com/");
        tf.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        tf.positionCaret(25);
        GridPane sp = new GridPane();
        sp.getChildren().add(wv);
        GridPane.setConstraints(tf, 1, 0, 0, 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(sp, 600, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

But getting this errors:

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rowSpan must be greater or equal to 1, but was 0
    at javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.setRowSpan(GridPane.java:346)
    at javafx.scene.layout.GridPane.setConstraints(GridPane.java:591)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:27)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    ... 1 more
```

Please help :(

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show which line is generating the exception (i.e which is line 27).

Comment: Showing an error at `GridPane.setConstraints(tf, 1, 0, 0, 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear: you are calling the method [`setConstraints(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#setConstraints-javafx.scene.Node-int-int-int-int-javafx.geometry.HPos-javafx.geometry.VPos-) and passing in 0 for `rowSpan` and `colSpan`. The error message says you cannot set `rowSpan` to zero. (You presumably cannot set `colSpan` to zero either.) Those restrictions would seem to make sense.

Comment: Okay ..you were right :) ..thanks ..but i would know one more thing .. I'm unable to see that TextField inside Frame.. Can you help me pls..

Comment: You forgot to add the text field to the grid pane.

Comment: But i can see `tf` here...  `GridPane.setConstraints(tf, 1, 0, 0, 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);`

Comment: But that doesn't add the `tf` to the grid pane, it merely sets the constraints. (It doesn't even refer to your grid pane, so there's no way it could.) Perhaps you should review the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102).

Comment: Thanks i resloved the issue :)